# Black screen appears while loading image in imageview after taking picture in camera360 App

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to take pic using camera360 app and when i click on tick mark image should load in the imageView. This is working fine with the Google Camera app. But the same pic if i load it from gallery then it is loaded properly in imageView.

```
    private void TakePic() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else{
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK ){
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i load my image in an imageview after selecting it from the gallery maybe it will help you, maybe not.

```
requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

on button click:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainComp_News_Edit.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainComp_News_Edit.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainComp_News_Edit.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: from gallery it is working fine, but when picture with Camera360 it is showing blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly because you are loading the image from the camera in the app in the main thread. Try wrapping the contents of **onActivityResult** in asynctask.